# protecting a staging Drupal environment

Tags: staging

I've been using this code block inspired by [Acquia](https://docs.acquia.com/articles/password-protect-your-non-production-environments-acquia-hosting) to protect a client's staging environment.

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '192.168.1.1') {

    $username = 'user';
$password = 'password';

if (!(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']==$username && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']==$password))) {
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="This site is protected"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
// Fallback message when the user presses cancel / escape
echo 'Access denied';
exit;
}
}
```

I'm finding that I'm getting mixed results with it though.

I can access fine - as can some users but others can't get the user/password to accept.

I did post the same thing on SO but kinda got shot down so hoped the Drupal community could be more indulging/enlightening as to where we're falling down.

Thanks in advance. Steven

Comment: hmm when you mention 'protect', what are you trying to do actually? Do you intent to not have this site accessible from the outside world is it? Then you may need to add server level authentication instead of at drupal level?

Comment: simple auth to stop people accessing without user/pass. I know you can do this with .htaccess but would rather not have to manage that between envs.

Comment: Kind of on a tangent but as I mentioned doing it on the server level with a Rewrite rule is much simpler. Sorry I do not have an example, some with more DevOps can help with that

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't have been shut down on SO as this is more a general PHP / Acquia hosting problem than it is with Drupal.

You should have your code echo out the contents of `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` & `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` in your "Access Denied" message; that will let the user inform you of exactly what's going on by the relaying the output of the script.

One of 2 things is going on to give inconsistent results:

1. The user's browser in question aren't sending the authentication header over (`Authorization:Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==` for "user" / "password")
2. The code executed at the time of user request isn't setting the correct vars `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` & `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` upon script execution (e.g. caching, something filtering out the `Authorization` header before it reaches the target host machine executing the PHP script).